# How to validate, that a comment written on a post really was written to that post?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I am working with AJAX, PHP and MySQL. In the following my PHP Code:

```
if(isset($_GET['postTextComment'])){

    // The text of the comment
    $htpc = htmlspecialchars($_GET['postTextComment'];);
    // ID of post, where comment was written on (comes from hidden input field in HTML)
    $postid = $_GET['pid'];
    // ID of the user written the comment
    $myid = getUID();

    // CHECK IF COMMENT IS A STRING
    if(is_string($htmlpostcomment)){

        // CHECK IF POST ID IS A NUMBER
        if(is_numeric($postid)){

            // CHECK IF POST IS EMPTY
            if($htmlpostcomment == "") {

                $errors = "Write something! Nyaaa~";

            // OR OVER 3K LETTERS   
            } elseif($htmlpostcomment > 3000) {

                $errors = "Too long! Nyaaa~";

            } else {

                $insertion = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO home_posts_comments (uid,pid,html,timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                $insertion->bind_param('ssss', $myid, $postid, $htpc, $posted_on);
                $insertion->execute();

                echo $htpc;
            }

        } else {
            $errors = "NYAAAA!~~~~~";
        }
    } else {
        $errors = "NYAAAA!~~~~~";
    }
}
```

Here I am checking, if the text that was sent through the input-field in HTML is a string and, whether the ID of the post, that the comment should show up eventually is numeric. And some other validations about empty input etc.

Now my AJAX:

```
$(document).on('click', '[data-action="post-comment"]', function(e) {

    // Stored id of the post, where comment should show up lately
    var postcomment_where = $(this).data('storeid');
    // Value of the comment-input field
    var commentLength = $('#posting-comment-data input[data-storeid="'+postcomment_where+'"]').val();

    /* (...Some validations...) */

    var data = $('#posting-comment-data[data-storeid="'+postcomment_where+'"]').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        data: data,
        type: "get",
        url: "/assets/templates/functions/home/post_comment.php",
        beforeSend: function(data){

            /* (...Show loader...) */

        },
        success: function(data){

            /* (...Hide loader, append post in post section...) */

        },
        error: function(data){

            /* (...Show some error...) */

        }
    });
}
```

Same checkt just for the front-end, to get more responsiveness for the user.

Last my HTML, and here's the thing I am struggling with:

```
<form id="posting-comment-data" data-storeid="(...ID of post...)" onsubmit="return false;">
    <!--- Comment text input field --->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Comment this..." name="postTextComment" id="postTextComment" data-storeid="(...ID of post...)">
    <!--- Stored ID of the post, where the comment shall show up lately --->
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="(...ID of post...)" autocomplete="off">

    <!--- Submit Button --->
    <button type="button" id="post-button-comment-(...ID of post...)" class="cs-button-send" data-storeid="(...ID of post...)" style="display:none;" data-action="post-comment">
        Submit comment
    </button>
</form>
```

The biiiig problem is now, that people could just open the developer tools for each broser and change the ID of the post in the hidden input field, so that the comment would show up on a different post. I have been struggling with that problem for some time now, but it doesn't seem like I get to a good solution for this.

The table in the database has rows for unique post ID, user ID, text and timestamp.

Comment: If you're concerned about people guessing `id` values, don't use incremental values. I'd suggest GUIDs instead. Also, if you want to ensure requests only come from valid locations, research CSRF tokens.

Comment: I'm a little curious why someone would go out of their way to write a comment for something ... when it would just be easier to go to that something else and write the comment using its provided form. Are you really having a big issue with people doing this? Plus, a comment for a post is a comment for the post. Relevance is an entirely different beast given the whole effluence of the internet.

Comment: You could use JWT tokens and include the ID in the token instead.  Any changes to the token will make the request not validate.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Of course it's totally dumb and useless, to do something like this. But my situation right now just gives people the opportunity to do something like this and believe me, the web is full of weird people that have no sense in life and are just programmed on freak off others. It's kinda for myself, I doesn't feel like the website I am writing is good enough, if there is something like this.

Comment: Well, it may be dumb and stupid, and someone may try to do it, but to what end does this cause harm is more of my question. Is this causing a shutdown, a crash, corruption, spam, or something? But I understand how you would want to validate every form field (the others provided some alternatives).

Comment: Okay I just understood how to use tokens, I am trying it with this method now.

Comment: Also, be sure to always check if the ID you are to work with, is a 'open for public' ID. Like if its an ID that is not yet posted, or was disabled... then obviously disallow the comment. And when you do, toss their IP into the firewall drop list for a day as a slap on the hand for their tomfoolery ;)

Comment: @IncredibleHat that's already implemented, but thank you for the advice anyways :)

Comment: Badabum, works totally fine with tokens. Thank you alot tho. My brain always almost implodes by thinking about solutions in PHP and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does users need to login to post comments? If so you can save it in server session variables. Which cannot be changed by the user.

Once a user loads a page set the session variable. Then on the ajax submission access that data by `$_SESSION['someid']` then update the database.

Comment: This is helpful, but please add a little more detail to the answer to help the OP.

Comment: Seems like a method as well, thank you alot. I've solved the problem by using tokens. I have created an extra table for post_tokens, where the post ID and a generated token for that post get stored by posting something. As soon as someone writes a comment and sends it, the PHP script validates if there is an entry for a post with the specific ID and a relating token that fits with the token from the input-field in the HTML script

Comment: Glad you are able to resolve it. Whenever possible handle things at the server end. Never trust client input. Whatever input is given by the client we must be able to validate it.